# Highest prime factor

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to find the highest prime factor of a number. Written the algorithm in C.
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long largestPrimeFactor(long long param);
long long squareRootOrClosest(long long param);
long long checkForHighestPrime(long long param);

long long main(){
    printf("%lld\n",largestPrimeFactor(600851475143L) );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

long long largestPrimeFactor(long long  param){
    long long k = squareRootOrClosest(param);
    long long l = checkForHighestPrime(k);
    return l;

    }

long long squareRootOrClosest(long long param){
    long long i =0;
    long long s =0;

    for (long long j = 1; j*j <param; j++){
        s = j;
    }
    return s;
}

long long checkForHighestPrime(long long param){
    long long d = 0;
    long long h = 0;

    for (long long i = 1; i <param/2; i++){

        d = param%i;

        if(d == 0){
            h = d;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

All I get is a 0

What am I missing?

Comment: `d = param%i` <-- `i` will be 0 on the first iteration.

Comment: @Michael edited, now I get a result 0, weird

Comment: 600851475143 is too large for a long

Comment: @Daniele Compiler seems to be ok with that

Comment: why dont you start the loop with `i=2`?

Comment: It will compile ok. But your number will be mod by 32 bit integer max range.

Comment: The logic of `checkForHighestPrime()` will guarantee that 0 be returned, because if some `d` is zero, then `h` will be zero, if none of `b` is zero, then `h` will also be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use long long. And edit the number as `600851475143L`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long largestPrimeFactor(long long param);
long squareRootOrClosest(long long param);
long checkForHighestPrime(long param);

int main(){
    printf("%I64d\n",largestPrimeFactor(600851475143) );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

long largestPrimeFactor(long long param){
    long k = squareRootOrClosest(param);
    long l = checkForHighestPrime(k);
    return l;

    }

long squareRootOrClosest(long long param){
    long s =0;

    for (long long j = 1; j*j <param; j++){
        s = j;
    }
    return s;
}

long checkForHighestPrime(long param){
    long d = 0;
    long h = 0;

    for (long i = 2; i <param/2; i++){

        d = param%i;

        if(d == 0){
            h = i;
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```